# What - if any - tax obligations would there be for lost and reclaimed money?

Tags: united-states, taxes, investment-property, maryland

Many years back I invested a few thousand dollars in a stock fund. My intention was to "buy and hold" and occasionally add a little here and there. However, life changes meant that I didn't have extra money to contribute. At some point, I must have missed a letter or something, as I recently received a notice from my state that said they had money from the fund in their "Unclaimed Property". I filed the necessary paperwork and received a check for what must have been the value of my holdings in the fund at the time it was declared "unclaimed".

When tax time rolls around, will I be responsible for any taxes (income or otherwise) on this money? (I live in Maryland in the United States.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since these funds were in a stock fund, you will be liable for capital gains.[1](https://finance.zacks.com/owe-taxes-unclaimed-funds-3226.html) Determining the cost basis might be tricky. I suggest trying to track down the fund's administrator or the brokerage you used to purchase the fund in order to determine your date of purchase and cost basis.